# Sort bibliography entries with respect to their logical sequence (part i and then part ii)

Tags: bibtex, sorting

In my bibliography I have the following two entries:

```
Hosseini, S.A., Shah, N., 2011a. Enzymatic hydrolysis of cellulose part ii: Population balance modelling of hydrolysis by exoglucanase and universal kinetic model. Biomass Bioenerg. 35,
3820–3840.
Hosseini, S.A., Shah, N., 2011b. Modelling enzymatic hydrolysis of cellulose part i: Population balance modelling of hydrolysis by endoglucanase. Biomass Bioenerg. 35, 3841–3848.
```

The problem is that they appear in reverse order from the point of view of logical sequence (part i should be before part ii). The bibliography style that I use (model2-names from elsevier) sorts the entries alphabetically but for these two entries I would like to force part i to appear before part ii.

Here are the `.bib` entries:

```
@ARTICLE{Hosseini2011,
  author = {Seyed Ali Hosseini and Nilay Shah},
  title = {Modelling enzymatic hydrolysis of cellulose part I: Population balance
    modelling of hydrolysis by endoglucanase},
  journal = {Biomass Bioenerg.},
  year = {2011},
  volume = {35},
  pages = {3841-3848},
  file = {:Hosseini and Shah 2011 - Enzymatic hydrolysis of cellulose part I.pdf:PDF},
  journaltitle = {Biomass and Bioenergy}
}

@ARTICLE{Hosseini2011a,
  author = {Seyed Ali Hosseini and Nilay Shah},
  title = {Enzymatic hydrolysis of cellulose part II: Population balance modelling
    of hydrolysis by exoglucanase and universal kinetic model},
  journal = {Biomass Bioenerg.},
  year = {2011},
  volume = {35},
  pages = {3820-3840},
  file = {:Hosseini and Shah 2011 - Enzymatic hydrolysis of cellulose part II universal kinetic model.pdf:PDF},
  journaltitle = {Biomass and Bioenergy}
}
```

Is there a way to hack it? Part II comes before Part I but the titles are arranged alphabetically (which is normal since 'Enzymatic' comes before 'Modelling').

Comment: What bibliography package (`natbib`, `biblatex`, ...) and style are you using (`plainnat` etc.)? A MWE might help.

Comment: I'm using bibtex (as in the question tag) and model2-names (which comes from Elsevier journals).

Comment: So you use no additional package such as `natbib` or `cite` - or do you by any chance use `elsarticle` which loads `natbib` internally? (Note that if you want to submit to a journal there is no point in modifying its styles.)

Comment: Please, add the `.bib` entries for the two items.

Comment: Well, elsarticle loads natbib. I don't want to change the style - the style works very well except that I would like to sort these two entries differently to make them appear in a logical manner (part I before part II).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution that (as far as I can tell) has been around since the very beginnings of BibTeX:

- Provide a macro called `\noopsort` in the preamble of your `.bib` file:

  ```
  @PREAMBLE{ "\newcommand{\noopsort}[1]{} " }
  ```

  Even though this macro would appear to do nothing, which is indeed the case at least as far as LaTeX is concerned, it has a very good use during BibTeX's *sorting* phase, as will become clear next.
- Modify the `key` and `year` fields of the two entries as follows:

  ```
  @ARTICLE{Hosseini2011a,
      title = {Modelling enzymatic hydrolysis of cellulose part {I}: Population 
               balance modelling of hydrolysis by endoglucanase},
      ...  
      year = {2011\noopsort{2011a}},
      ...
  }

  @ARTICLE{Hosseini2011b,
      title = {Enzymatic hydrolysis of cellulose part {II}: Population balance 
               modelling of hydrolysis by exoglucanase and universal kinetic model},
      ...
      year = {2011\noopsort{2011b}},
      ...
  }
  ```

With these additions to the year fields, entry `Hosseini2011a` will always be shown before `Hossseini2011b`. The reason this method works is that during BibTeX's sorting run, at which time the entries are sorted first alphabetically by author(s) and next numerically by year, the `\noopsort{2011a}` and `\noopsort{2011b}` particles are not discarded; and, since 'a' comes before 'b' alphabetically, the sorting order will be what you want it to be. Later, after BibTeX has done its sorting job, LaTeX will come along and ignore the `\noopsort` instructions while it's actually typesetting the bibliography.

Comment: I get something funny here: when I cite `\citet{Hosseini2011a, Hosseini2011b}` I get `Hosseini and Shah (2011, ?)`. Why the question mark? If I delete the `\noopsort` commands from the `.bib` then it appears correctly (but they are sorted incorrectly, of course).

Comment: @remus - Did you update the keys of the two entries? (The contents of the two entries aren't the same in your original posting and in my answer.)

Comment: Here is a link to how my .bib looks like: http://imgur.com/a/6ozXG#0

Comment: @remus - Thanks for providing the link. Real quick: Did you also rerun LaTeX/BibTeX/LaTeX/LaTeX after modifying the `.bib` file? The reason I ask is that the "key" `Hosseini2011b` is new to the `.bib` file, and LaTeX and BibTeX won't know about it until one runs a full recompilation. (Similarly, unless one performs a full recompilation, `Hosseini2011a` will be pointing to the entry that used to be keyed to `Hosseini2011`.)

Comment: I refreshed everything (latex/bibtex/latex/latex). I just checked the `.bbl` file and it is updated with the new keys.

Comment: It works well if I place the `\noopsort` commands in the title of my references (I just tested).

Comment: @remus - Thanks for letting me know that things seem to be working correctly now.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, the style sorts by title when the author and year information is the same. Thus you can help BibTeX in finding the correct one first.

```
@ARTICLE{Hosseini2011,
  author = {Seyed Ali Hosseini and Nilay Shah},
  title = {{\SORTNOOP{a}}{Modelling} enzymatic hydrolysis of cellulose part {I}: {Population} balance
    modelling of hydrolysis by endoglucanase},
  journal = {Biomass Bioenerg.},
  year = {2011},
  volume = {35},
  pages = {3841-3848},
  file = {:Hosseini and Shah 2011 - Enzymatic hydrolysis of cellulose part I.pdf:PDF},
  journaltitle = {Biomass and Bioenergy}
}

@ARTICLE{Hosseini2011a,
  author = {Seyed Ali Hosseini and Nilay Shah},
  title = {{\SORTNOOP{b}}{Enzymatic} hydrolysis of cellulose part {II}: {Population} balance modelling
    of hydrolysis by exoglucanase and universal kinetic model},
  journal = {Biomass Bioenerg.},
  year = {2011},
  volume = {35},
  pages = {3820-3840},
  file = {:Hosseini and Shah 2011 - Enzymatic hydrolysis of cellulose part II universal kinetic model.pdf:PDF},
  journaltitle = {Biomass and Bioenergy}
}
```

Add also `\newcommand{\SORTNOOP}[1]{}` to your document preamble or add the line

```
@PREAMBLE{"\newcommand{\SORTNOOP}[1]{}"}
```

to your `.bib` file.

Note also that `I` and `II` should be braced to keep their case; I also braced the first word after the colon, which seems better. Also the first word in the title must be braced, because otherwise BibTeX would lowercase it.

Comment: This method works because the `elsarticle` bibliography styles do indeed seem to sort by the contents of the `title` field if the contents of the `author` and `year` fields are the same. However, this isn't the case for many other `.bst` files. It may be "safer" to insert the `\SORTNOOP` instructions in the entries' `year` fields (since BibTeX will always sort on that field).